# How to get terminal access to a php/AngularJS app deployed using opsWorks

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, opsworks

**Background:** I have a php backend application (cakephp with dependencies resolved with composer), and javascript front end (AngularJS, using bower for dependency management), with the repository on bitbucket.

I was able to successfully deploy it using opsworks.

Problems:

1. I need terminal access to the app layer to run shell commands such as composer install, bower install. How do I do this?
2. Is it better to do a manual deployment (set up the ec2 instanstances mmanually and ssh into the VM) instead of using opsWorks?
3. Generally what would be the best approach to deploy such an application?

Thankyou and apologies if my question has issues.

Answer (score 1):

1. This is basically missing the main point of OpsWorks (and configuration management in general). You should be using OpsWorks to do these things for you. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/opsworks/latest/userguide/customizing.html
2. This is an opinion issue and depends mostly on you and your application.
3. This is an opinion issue and depends mostly on you and your application.

Comment: Thankyou. Will look into it and come up with a more constructive question.

Answer (score -1):

You should be **[writing chef deployment recipes to do this!](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/opsworks/latest/userguide/create-custom-deploy.html)**

Currently it is easier to get set up using s3 without opsworks however opsworks is more scalable and gives you a warm fuzzy feeling when your recipies automate deployment flawlessly! [citation needed]

You can still SSH into your instances much like you'd connect to an s3 instance. In **Opsworks** go to **instances** -> **SSH** and follow instructions, something like this

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/aws-test.pem ubuntu@xx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

EDIT:I explained that SSHing into opsworks boxes is usually **a bad idea**.